# while downloading eml file by default it is opening in notepad it should open in outlook

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

while downloading .eml file it is opening in notepad by default. but it should open in mail client like outlook express. but after saving instead of opening directly and opening from the downloaded path I am able to open it in outlook. please  provide the setting to open .eml file in outlook. browser is Mozilla Firefox.

Comment: This question is more appropriate for the Firefox support forum: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/products/firefox I don't know if anyone here would have a solution for this.